# Asterisk server for unlimited cell phone calling?

Tags: asterisk, pbx

Does anyone know if Asterisk server can do the following?

I have 10 freelance programmers each working from a different city, each with their own cell phone. I want to have one business phone number like 111-222-3333. When clients call in, they must enter the extension of the developer they wish to reach. They are then connected to the corresponding freelance programmer's cell phone.

The goals are:

1) never expose the freelance programmer's cell phone number. Clients should only be aware of the business number + extension

2) the freelance programmer should have the business number 111-222-3333 as one of his "favourite" numbers because favourite numbers have unlimited talking minutes. All clients call in via the 111-222-3333 can talk to the freelancer indefinitely without incurring extra cell phone talk-time charges.

Is an Asterisk server the optimal solution for my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, is possible and from my point of view is the best solution. For calling your programmers you can use a different phone number, not 111-222-3333. I use the same solution for a marketing team and it works perfect. Short example:

```
exten => 111-222-3333,1,Answer()
exten => ... play IVR
exten => 111-222-3333,3,Dial(SIP/nr_of_programmer@out-sipaccount,120,Tw)
```